# How do I make an object which hides 3d objects behind it, but shows my video background?

Tags: node-editor, tracking

I am currently interested in tracking 3d objects into my videos. I am not sure how to create what looks like a hole in the ground. If I used a sqaure with no top face, the outer sides of the cube would still appear over the video, I need only the inside of the cube to be seen.

Is it possible to make a sort of plane object that hides the 3d objects behind it, but still shows my video background?

-Owen

Comment: some picture will give a clue what you're trying to achieve. for now it's unclear. note that everything is possible, though )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mechanic says, what you ask is not clear, please show some screenshots. Do you want to create an alpha transparency wherever you want on your 3D object? The *Holdout* shader does that. Don't forget to activate the *Properties* panel > *Render > Film > Transparent* option.

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants to create a 3D object that looks like a hole in the ground and add it over some footage of a ground (so only the top + inside of the 3D object would be visible). The question is worded in a confusing way.

Comment: ok understood, I think Holdout is still the right solution, no?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. As Luciano says, I am trying to make an overlay that could appear as a hole in the ground. I tried the holdout shader and it seems to work for what I am trying to do. Thank you very much.